# How to count total of leaves(fetching from database) of each user  separately in MVC-3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I wants to count the total leaves of each users from the database.
and wants to display it in telerik gridview in **Asp.Net MVC-3 (Aspx)**.

i have a gridview with two columns. first column displays the names of all the employees/users and 2nd column will display the total leaves of that users.

my **database** is as below

**leave_master**

leave_id (primary key)
user_id  (foreign key with user_id of table user_master)
leave_days

**user_master**

user_id (primary key)
user_real_name

My Model files are as below

name - **LeaveGridview.cs**

```
<pre>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace ProjectManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class LeaveGridview
    {

        public int user_id { get; set; }

        public string user_name { get; set; }

        public string user_real_name { get; set; }    

        public int leave_id { get; set; }

        public decimal leave_days { get; set; }


    }
}
</pre>
```

2nd file

name - **LeaveGridviewFetch.cs**

```
<pre>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectManagementSystem.Models
{

    public class LeaveGridviewFetch
    {



        public static IList&lt;LeaveGridview&gt; all()
        {
            IList&lt;LeaveGridview&gt; result =
                (IList&lt;LeaveGridview&gt;)HttpContext.Current.Session["leave1"];

            if (result == null)
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Session["leave1"] = result =
                    (from l in new ProjectManagementSystemEntities3().leave_master
                     select new LeaveGridview
                     {
                         user_id = l.user_id,
                         leave_id = l.leave_id,
                         user_real_name = l.user_master.user_real_name,



                     }).ToList();

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
</pre>
```

My contgroller file 
name **LeaveController.cs**

```
<pre>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectManagementSystem.Models;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc;

namespace LeaveModule.Controllers
{
    public class LeaveController : Controller
    {
        public ProjectManagementSystemEntities3 pb = new ProjectManagementSystemEntities3();

  public ActionResult LeaveShow()
        {
            var leave_master = pb.leave_master.Include("user_master");
            ViewBag.leave_id = new SelectList(pb.user_master, "user_id", "user_real_name");
            return View(leave_master.ToList());
        }

 [GridAction]
        public ActionResult _SelectBatchEditing()
        {
            return View(new GridModel(LeaveGridviewFetch.all()));
        }

}
}

</pre>
```

my view is

name **LeaveShow.ascx**

```
<pre>

&lt;%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %&gt;

&lt;asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"&gt;
    LeaveShow
&lt;/asp:Content&gt;

&lt;asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"&gt;

&lt;%  Html.Telerik().Grid&lt;ProjectManagementSystem.Models.LeaveGridview&gt;() 
                       .Name("grid")
                       .DataKeys(keys =&gt;
                       {
                           keys.Add(l =&gt; l.leave_id);
                       })

                       .DataBinding(dataBinding =&gt;
                        dataBinding.Ajax()
                       .Select("_SelectBatchEditing", "Leave") // Leave is controller name
                       )

                        .Columns(columns =&gt;
                       {

                           columns.Bound(l =&gt; l.user_real_name).Width(200); 

                           columns.Bound(l =&gt; l.leave_days).Width(150);

                       })


                       .Groupable()
                       .Pageable()
                       .Filterable()
                       .Render();

                       %&gt;


&lt;/asp:Content&gt;


</pre>
```

i wanna output like

**name---------------total_ leaves**

abc----------------  10

xyz----------------  12

pqr----------------  06

So how can i do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Who is down voting my all questions and Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the `leave_id` in your query if you want to aggregate the days.
I would also change the name `leave_days` in the `LeaveGridView` model to `total_leave_days`. I assume that there is an `IEnumerable<leave_master>` on your `user_master` object called `leave_masters`. Change the query in LeaveGridFetch to:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Session["leave1"] = result =
                (from l in new ProjectManagementSystemEntities3().user_master
                 select new LeaveGridview
                 {
                     user_id = l.user_id,
                     user_real_name = l.user_real_name,
                     total_leave_days = l.leave_masters.Sum(i => i.leave_days)
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: what about the name. It display the names more then one time. so it doesn't sum up the leave days.

Comment: I don't understand, this query will return one object for every user in user_master.